# CCFileUtils naming convention not working so images can't be found

Tags: ios, xcode, cocos2d-iphone

I'm pretty new to xcode and apps so got some source code and am learning by 'playing'. I've been changing some file names and now my images won't load.

I have:

```
    [CCFileUtils setiPadSuffix:@"-ipad"];           
    [CCFileUtils setRetinaDisplaySuffix:@"-hd"];
```

which works for all the other images in the source code but the ones I have changed are not being searched for with '-ipad' appended to the file name. When I create the files and add them without the suffix i.e. image.png rather than image-ipad.png they are loaded normally. I want to have the suffix naming convention though.

I have checked the files are named correctly (no rogue capital letters etc)

I have loaded them into the project (copy items into destination group folder, and create groups for any added folders)

I have checked that the files are there in copy bundle resources in the targets build phases.

I've also cleaned/build/relaunched etc many times including deleting the app from the sim and also full computer restart!! Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK folks I've managed to solve this one after two days of painful brain wracking! Whereas most of the images are used interchangeably across the app, some are used for specific levels. The files are named the same i.e background.png but level1/background.png might be different to level2/background.png

There are sections of code that specify specific folders by using a custom getFullPath method written in.

Due to this, instead of images being loaded into the project in groups they needed to be loaded in with the folders being references (Blue folders not yellow).

I finally figured it out by looking into the Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator files that were being generated.

Also its worth noting that I had to have both sd folders with no file appendices available as well as the -hd.png, -ipad.png and -ipad-hd.png files that were being used as well. So even though I was running on the ipad sim I had to have the iphone sd files available too.

Hope this helps someone in the future!